# Renumbering files with batch script multiple counters

Tags: batch-file

i have tried to find a way to rename files in a folder that gets generated from a software.
What i need to do is to give the file a new name and then add multiple number sequences as a suffix. [Name]-[n].[n].[n] For example: Project-1.2.5
Say if i have these files:

```
MeanEdgeProfile_2022-01-21_12-14-32.csv  
MeanEdgeProfile_2022-01-21_12-16-09.csv  
MeanEdgeProfile_2022-01-21_12-17-43.csv  
MeanEdgeProfile_2022-01-21_12-22-15.csv  
MeanEdgeProfile_2022-01-21_12-23-56.csv
```

They are generated by date and time and i would like to rename them like this from oldest to newest

```
Project-1.1.1.csv  
Project-1.1.2.csv  
Project-1.1.3.csv  
Project-1.1.4.csv  
Project-1.1.5.csv
```

When i get to #5 on the last digit the next 5 files should look like this:

```
Project-1.2.1.csv  
Project-1.2.2.csv  
Project-1.2.3.csv  
Project-1.2.4.csv  
Project-1.2.5.csv
```

And when the middle # gets to a certain value the first # changes to the next value and the previous values resets to 1 again and starts to count again.
Basically each file represent one out of multiple measurements of one part where [n1].[n2].[n3] describes witch file goes where for each part, side of the part and placement of the measurement.

- [n1] = part number
- [n2] = what side of the part
- [n3] = what measurement on that side

I need to have some variables to control this behavior because each measurement series is not the same as another, so all [n] need to have a variable that tells when to count the next value up 1+ and then reset the later ones back to 1 again.

Now I'm doing this manually and it takes alot of time to rename everything so i need to automate this task somehow.
I dont know if this is possible in a easy way to get this done in batch script.
Maybe there is some kind of software that supports this feature already. But those i have tried and looked att only supports regular sequence numbering and not in this way i need it to be done.
Here is a picture of a series of files i manually renamed

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLSwQ.png)

Comment: In future, please format your question body to something we can better read and understand, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code performs the proper numbering:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set the limits for 2nd and 3rd parts:
set /A "L2=4, L3=5"

set /A "n1=1, n2=1, n3=0"
for /L %%i in (1,1,25) do (
   set /A "n3+=1, v3=(L3-n3>>31)+1, n3=n3*v3+^!v3, n2+=^!v3, v2=(L2-n2>>31)+1, n2=n2*v2+^!v2, n1+=^!v2"
   echo %%i: !n1!.!n2!.!n3!
)
```

Output example:

```
1: 1.1.1
2: 1.1.2
3: 1.1.3
4: 1.1.4
5: 1.1.5
6: 1.2.1
7: 1.2.2
8: 1.2.3
9: 1.2.4
10: 1.2.5
11: 1.3.1
12: 1.3.2
13: 1.3.3
14: 1.3.4
15: 1.3.5
16: 1.4.1
17: 1.4.2
18: 1.4.3
19: 1.4.4
20: 1.4.5
21: 2.1.1
22: 2.1.2
23: 2.1.3
24: 2.1.4
25: 2.1.5
```

Just change the example `for /L` loop by a loop over the files and execute the `ren` command